# problem with mouse event for absolute position div

Tags: jquery, mouseout

I have list of images on mouseover on those have to show some information. Problem is mouse events are not trigger for the info div.

```
#team_div{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

#pop_div{
  width:300px;
  padding:5px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  background:#fefefe;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}

#pop_div img{ 
  margin:10px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
```

.

```
<div id="team_div" class="team_div_loading">
<div id="pop_div"></div>
<table>

  list of images

</table>
</div>
```

.

```
$('#team_div > table img').hover(function() {
  var top = this.parentNode.offsetTop; 
  var left = this.parentNode.offsetLeft; 
  var img =$(this).attr('src');
  var id =$(this).attr('id');
  var content = $("#" + id + "p").html();
  $("#pop_div").show();
  $("#pop_div").css('top', top-11 +'px');
  $("#pop_div").css('left', left-12 +'px');
  $("#pop_div").html('<img src="' + img + '"/>' + content );
  $("#pop_div").fadeIn(700);
});

$("#pop_div").mouseout(function(){
  $("this").hide();
});
```

In this if function is called for image on hover, none of the mouse events are triggering for pop_div.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: is the hover function working?

Comment: yup.. hover function is working.. if i comment hover functionality mouse out functionality wil work for absolute position div

Comment: what happens if you put `alert("mouseout")` in the mouseout function?

Comment: Its not triggering any event, even click event for other tags als0. I guess some problem with hover function.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can not use  in  element, use a div or a ul li structure for that, I did that by inserting img tags in a

```
<div class="imageDiv"></div>
```

and edit the jquery function with

```
$('#team_div>.imageDiv img').hover(function () {
        var top = this.parentNode.offsetTop;
        var left = this.parentNode.offsetLeft;
        var img = $(this).attr('src');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var content = $("#" + id + "p").html();
        $("#pop_div").show();
        $("#pop_div").css('top', top - 11 + 'px');
        $("#pop_div").css('left', left - 12 + 'px');
        $("#pop_div").html('<img src="' + img + '"/>' + content);
        $("#pop_div").fadeIn(700);
    });
```

You were just using a wrong jquery selector. I dont know what you are trying to do with the image hover function, but it is working with the above changes.